# ListBox Multiselect in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have created a form to get all the field header names, but I'm unable to select multiple fields. Attached is for your reference.
[image]

Following is the code used to get the Headers from the Master Table:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
'Call GetColumnNameFromIndex
'Call List4_Click
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open "SELECT * FROM Master_DataBase", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
' Note: adOpenForwardOnly and adLockReadOnly are the default values '
' for the CursorType and LockType arguments, so they are optional here '
' and are shown only for completeness '

Dim ii As Integer
Dim ss As String
For ii = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
    ss = ss & "," & rst.Fields(ii).Name
Next ii

Me.List4.RowSource = ss
Debug.Print ss
Me.Requery

End Sub
```

Comment: Set listbox Multi-Select property to Simple or Extended. Don't need VBA to load listbox with fieldnames - set RowSourceType property to FieldList and RowSource to table. Will need VBA and QueryDefs to modify query object with selected fields.

Comment: @June7 Thank you. I have tried and the field list is reflecting correctly. Please help me with the other requirement mentioned above. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have too many elements to your question, it is too broad. Do research on VBA to modify QueryDefs. When you have specific code with issue post another question.

Comment: Okay @June7, I'll post another question on VBA part and mark this as answered, Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Set your properties to Simple or Extended.

[image]

Sample VBA code may look like this.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub cmdOpenQuery_Click()

On Error GoTo Err_cmdOpenQuery_Click
    Dim MyDB As DAO.Database
    Dim qdef As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strWhere As String
    Dim strIN As String
    Dim flgSelectAll As Boolean
    Dim varItem As Variant
    
    Set MyDB = CurrentDb()
    
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblCompanies"
    
    'Build the IN string by looping through the listbox
    For i = 0 To lstCounties.ListCount - 1
        If lstCounties.Selected(i) Then
            If lstCounties.Column(0, i) = "All" Then
                flgSelectAll = True
            End If
            strIN = strIN & "'" & lstCounties.Column(0, i) & "',"
        End If
     Next i
     
    'Create the WHERE string, and strip off the last comma of the IN string
    strWhere = " WHERE [strCompanyCountries] in (" & Left(strIN, Len(strIN) - 1) & ")"
    
    'If "All" was selected in the listbox, don't add the WHERE condition
    If Not flgSelectAll Then
        strSQL = strSQL & strWhere
    End If
    
    MyDB.QueryDefs.Delete "qryCompanyCounties"
    Set qdef = MyDB.CreateQueryDef("qryCompanyCounties", strSQL)
    
    'Open the query, built using the IN clause to set the criteria
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryCompanyCounties", acViewNormal
    
    'Clear listbox selection after running query
    For Each varItem In Me.lstCounties.ItemsSelected
        Me.lstCounties.Selected(varItem) = False
    Next varItem
    
    
Exit_cmdOpenQuery_Click:
    Exit Sub
    
Err_cmdOpenQuery_Click:

   If Err.Number = 5 Then
        MsgBox "You must make a selection(s) from the list", , "Selection Required !"
        Resume Exit_cmdOpenQuery_Click
    Else
    'Write out the error and exit the sub
        MsgBox Err.Description
        Resume Exit_cmdOpenQuery_Click
    End If

End Sub
```

Please customize to your specific needs.

[image]

[image]