# Microsoft Access - Filtering a form based on check boxes for one field

Tags: forms, ms-access, checkbox, filter

I have a form with a list of farmers and all of the livestock they own (if a farmer has multiple types of livestock, they are listed in separate records). What I want to do is allow the user to filter the form so they can see only the farmers that have certain types of livestock, depending on what they check/highlight. I want them to be able to select multiple livestock (I figured out how to filter one type of livestock, but not more than that) There is a button the user clicks on to run the filter. I know this can be done, but I can't figure out how. I've searched for answers without much luck.

Here's an example:

Bob has Horses

Bob has Beef Cows

Sally has Horses

Sally has Goats

If the user clicks "Beef Cows" and then clicks on the 'Filter' button, only Bob's information would appear. If the user clicks "Horses" and "Beef Cows", Bob and Sally would both appear.

**UPDATE**:
I made this WAY more complicated than it needed to be. See below for the solution that worked for me.

Comment: So is data really "Livestock A" or is it "Pig"? Edit question to show sample data as text tables. This will require VBA code to build filter criteria and apply to form or report. One common approach is to use a multi-select listbox and loop through listbox selections to build a string array for use in IN() clause: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE Livestock IN('A', 'C')`. Using checkboxes will require multiple `If Then` blocks to build the string. Listbox is more compact code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ListBox Multiselect in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66240893/listbox-multiselect-in-ms-access)

Comment: It would be better to build the string with livestock IDs `SELECT * FROM table WHERE LivestockID IN (1,3)`. The alternative criteria would be multiple equality expressions with OR operator `SELECT * FROM table WHERE LivestockID = 1 OR LivestockID = 3`.

Comment: Listbox also provides more versatility in design. If ever add a new livestock (ostrich?) don't have to redesign form to add another checkbox, it will just be another item in listbox based on Livestock table.

Comment: More on building filter criteria http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: June7, wow, thanks for all of the information! Let me see if I can find something among your suggestions that will work (and yes, Livestock A is a simply a placeholder for a specific livestock, like Horses).

Comment: @June7, so far, no luck. The first option opens a query and deletes all of the data I have in it (obviously I'm doing something wrong but not sure what). The second option with AllenBrowne doesn't allow for multiple selection.

Comment: Pulling farmers that have both animals is different from pulling farmers that have at least one of them. The first is more difficult, especially if you want to match on more than 2. Unfortunately, I don't think the referenced examples provide for the first which might need another VBA custom function.

Comment: Data should be posted as text tables (or SQL code to create tables and append data), not images.

Comment: @June7 Very sorry about that. I'll post the SQL code. I know more about Access than the every joe, but when it comes to comes to people in the programming field, I'm a greenhorn.

Comment: The AllenBrowne solution does allow for multiple selection. This is what a multi-select listbox is for. There is a link in Allen's tutorial to another tutorial for that. If you read the entire tutorial you should have seen it.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was creating a button with the following VBA code:

```
Private Sub cmdFilterButtonTake2_Click()
DoCmd.GoToControl "LivestockType"
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdFilterMenu
End Sub
```

Where "LivestockType" is the Field I wanted to sort. It worked like a charm!

I also created a button to clear the Filter

```
Private Sub cmdRemoveFilter_Click()
Me.Filter = ""
Me.FilterOn = False
End Sub
```