# Custom Filter Button for Some Columns in Access Database

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have a table in Access database. I want to add filter button on a report for only specific columns. Like in a report view, there will be 3 to 4 buttons available on top (for those columns) and when I click on that it will show their values and then the whole data can be filtered. And Also in a report view I want to sort the fields. I have searched a a lot but unable to find a solution.

Comment: Review comments to recent question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70671627/microsoft-access-filtering-a-form-based-on-check-boxes-for-one-field

Comment: What do you mean by 'sort fields' - records are sorted, not fields.

Comment: Create a query from table. Use a `FORM` and `TextBox` to enter data and use those textboxes as query criteria. Then use that query as data-source of the report.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example